# listen to swipe event while ignoring click

Tags: javascript, html, angular, swiper.js

Is it somehow possible that a component listen to a swiper event while ignore the click. Meaning the component under it will then be triggered by the click event?

[image]

- The blue line is my swiper area, built in to let people open the sidenav with a swipe.
- But I also need the user to be able to click on the arrow button.
- I cannot move the button over the blue line.

#### Code structure

```html
 <sidenav></sidenav>
 <section>
   <button>my arrow</button>
 </section>
```

Comment: You can't give it a high z-index?

Comment: @Kinglish Yes I can't, `sidenav` have to still over  `section`